# Optimize the creation of a matrix/data frame

Tags: r, optimization, extract, data-manipulation, coding-efficiency

I am trying to create a new matrix/data frame using a list of values that match the values of a column in the old data frame. Also for the new matrix/data frame I want to preserve the order from the list of values used for match. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
#A list of values used for matching
time.new <- c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6)
#The old data frame which I would match on the column of time.old
old <- data.frame(time.old=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
```

I got a solution (see below) by using `merge` and `order` but I want to avoid `merge` and `order` because they really slow things down and I have a much larger dataset. Matrix outcome is preferred as data frame can also be slow (for further manipulations) So any ideas will be appreciated!

```
time.new <- data.frame(id = 1:length(time.new), time=time.new)
new_dataframe <- merge(x = time.new, y = old, by.x = "time", by.y="time.old", all.x = TRUE)
new_dataframe <- new_dataframe[order(new_dataframe$id), ]
new_dataframe$id <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to join `time.new` and `time.old` and get corresponding
`y` value.

```
set.seed(123)
time.new <- c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6)
old <- data.frame(time.old=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
cbind(time = time.new, y = old$y[match(time.new, old$time.old)])

#      time       y
# [1,]    2 -0.2302
# [2,]    3  1.5587
# [3,]    4  0.0705
# [4,]    3  1.5587
# [5,]    4  0.0705
# [6,]    5  0.1293
# [7,]    4  0.0705
# [8,]    5  0.1293
# [9,]    6  1.7151
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! @Ronak Shah